# Android "Turn Over" motion / gesture detection like Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android

I want to implement a certain action within my Android app which is to be triggered when a user "turns over" his phone.

Exactly similar to what I do to mute incoming calls on my Samsung Galaxy S3. Note that there is no touch involved anywhere here. It's all about motions here.

What all sensors besides the accelerometer would I need to listen to? Can anybody help me with the code for implementing this particular motion / gesture recognition.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Display.getRotation(). See the [official Android doc link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html).